# Php website is running on local server, not on web server

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web, server

Ok I have a website that uses Php, javascript, html, css and sql. (just clarifying for detail).

I've been coding it for a whole month, and it's finally ready to upload. So I put all the files on my web server, and every page is blank when you view the page in the browser, but all the code is still there on the server.

I check the page source, and all that's there is the html comment at the top of my included `header.php` file. (`<-- some comment -->`) I am pretty advanced at this stuff, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Things that are not wrong (I triple checked):

1. Wrong file paths (also url address)
2. Wrong database connection information
3. file permissions
4. php server configuration (I have other similar sites on the same server)
5. The .htaccess file. If there is anything else you can think of that may be wrong please help me!

Comment: Hi Joshua, if you could provide a bit more details such as screenshots or some of your source code to the pages you are trying to access, we can take a look at see what's wrong.

Comment: Definitely needs more information. Screenshot of your web server structure, home page source, and htaccess should do it.

Comment: I am highly aware that some code would be helpful, but I'm very wary of making my php code public. I'll provide some code if I don't get any suggestions, but I think I'll play it safe for now and wait.

Comment: Sure Joshua, your privacy is totally understandable. How about a link to your site if it's public? Or just snippets of your code that you think might be causing the problem.

Comment: I'm very sorry guys, I got it working now, I just panicked when it wouldn't work. I shouldn't have posted this without taking a calming break or something, it's just that this site is due tomorrow. Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but it reminded me that I once was in the situation that my live server didn't accept

```
<?
```

as a mark of the beginning of PHP-code. I needed to use

```
<?php
```

and only then everything worked. Did you check this?

Comment: I suspect short tags were address in 
`4 .php server configuration (I have other similar sites on the same server)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but yes I always use <?php tags.

Comment: I found the problem. It was that I had a set of php tags inside another one. Apparently my xampp server doesn't mind, but the host server does mind. Anyway thanks!